# Does Kurento supports hardware decoding by utilizing the GPU (RTSP Streaming)?

Tags: gpu, hardware, rtsp, decoding, kurento

I want to render the RTSP streams which comes from the IP cameras on to the web browser. In this context, when an IP camera supports one codec and web browser supports another codec. Here, transcoding comes in to the picture.

**Does Kurento framework do this transcoding using hardware decoding by utilizing the GPU (Graphics processing unit)? I mean Hardware-Accelerated Streaming.**

Answer (score 0):

There is no GPU support in Kurento.